# Godaddy not sending email to google smtp

Tags: gmail, phpmailer, godaddy-api

Our organization emails are purchased from google workspace and website is hosted on godaddy vps. For sending emails I use gmail smtp but the email is not sent, then I tried to create a local email on cpanel but whenever an email is sent to local email it bounces. What to do

Answer (score 1):

That's because GoDaddy is junk. They block outbound SMTP, so you have to use their servers, and gmail doesn't allow you to do that while using domains hosted by gmail (because it's forgery), so any mail that you submit will be rejected. Change to a competent hosting provider, or switch your email service to host on GoDaddy too (which I don't recommend).

Comment: So it's basically use their services or things wont work

Comment: Pretty much, yes

Comment: Expanding on @Synchro's correct answer:  I spoke to GoDaddy Level 2 support today and was told that they block third-party email relays (such as smtp.google.com) in order to prevent spam. He said that with their Virtual Private Server or Dedicated server plans, users can access GoDaddy's relays, but still not access third-party relays.